# What is the new feature about constexpr std::string with gcc 12.1

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, stdstring, gcc12

case1:

```cpp
#include <string>

inline constexpr std::string test(std::string s) noexcept
{
    return s + "xxx";
}

int main()
{
    auto s = test("abc");
}
```

c++20 with gcc 12.1 is built okay, c++17 with gcc 12.1 or c++20/17 with gcc 11.1 was failed,

`constexpr std::string`, Is this a new feature, or what does this mean?

case2:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::string test{"xxxxxx"};
}
```

And in this case both failed, what is the difference between these two cases.

Comment: Not quite sure what your confusion is here - you seem to have partially answered your own questions, because the `std::string::operator+()` is `constexpr` since C++20.

Comment: `because the std::string::operator+() is constexpr since C++20.` - This is supported by gcc12.1? gcc 11.1 c++ 20 is not supported yet?

Comment: When asking about compiler errors, please always add the error message verbatim.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different use cases of `constexpr` here:

1. `constexpr` functions
2. `constexpr` objects

When you see it on a function such as

```
inline constexpr std::string test(std::string s) noexcept
{
    return s + "xxx";
}
```

the `constexpr` is not part of the return type, in the same way that `inline` is not part of the return type; it is part of the function definition. In this case, `constexpr` says "this function can possibly be run at compile time".

The second use case you've mentioned is tagging an object definition as `constexpr`. In this use case, you're telling the compiler that this must be a compile time constant, and currently `std::string` objects cannot be marked `constexpr` due to the dynamic memory allocation that it does which it performed at runtime.

One thing you may have seen is that the `std::string` constructor was marked `constexpr` in C++20. This does not mean that you can create `constexpr` instances of `std::string`. It just means that `std::string` can be constructed and used within `constexpr` contexts (like a `constexpr` function).

You may then ask "if `std::string` requires runtime allocation, how can it be used within a `constexpr` function?". The basic answer is that the compiler uses a different allocation strategy to enable it, and does extra magic to make sure no undefined behaviour occurs. You can see more info [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0784r1.html).

To give a bit more information about `constexpr` functions, note that I said it could "possibly" be run at compile time. A function marked `constexpr` can be run at either compile time or runtime, depending on the arguments it's called with

```
constexpr int double_val(int x) { return 2 * x; }

int main() {
    const int y = double_val(4); // likely ran at compile time
    
    int input = 0;
    std::cin >> input;
    const int z = double_val(input); // run at runtime
}
```

If you want to force the function to only run at compile time, that's what C++20's `consteval` keyword allows you to do.

```
consteval int double_val(int x) { return 2 * x; }

int main() {
    const int y = double_val(4); // fine, ran at compile time
    
    int input = 0;
    std::cin >> input;
    const int z = double_val(input); // ERROR, could not compile
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following ***might*** not compile either, for you:

```
constexpr auto s = test("abc");
```

There's a slight semantical difference between a `constexpr` object and a `constexpr` function.

A `constexpr` object ***must*** be a compile-time constant.

A `constexpr` function ***might*** be a compile-time constant if everything in the function is a constant expression. Subsequently, the result of the function is a constant expression if its parameters are, and obviously not if they're not.

What appears to be happening is that your compiler hasn't yet implemented the `constexpr` version of the `std::string` constructor in C++20, but has implemented the `constexpr` `+` operator.

Hence the function gets compiled without a constant expression as its parameter, but since its result is not assigned to a `constexpr` object this is not immediately apparent.

But assigning the function's result to a `constexpr` reveals the ugly truth.

Comment: A `constexpr` constructor doesn't imply that you can create `constexpr` objects of that type, only that objects of that type can be used within `constexpr` functions.

Comment: @MattCummins No, `constexpr` ctor **does** imply you can create `constexpr` objects, in fact that is the purpose of `constexpr` ctors.

Comment: @Quimby My understanding is that it enables `std::string` for use within a constant expression, so long as the string is destroyed because the end, which means you cannot create `constexpr` instances of it. A good example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70571714/20064300

Comment: Typo: destroyed before* the end of the expression